# How can I perfectly train/fit a neural network to a few random inputs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to perfectly fit a neural network (in Matlab) to some random input but I always get stuck in local optima. It should just fit the sample input perfectly, no need for generalization, that's why I disabled the data division (train vs. test data).

Here is my code:

```
y = [];
a = 1;
b = 100;
y = round((b-a).*rand(10,1) + a);
y = y';

x = [];
for i = 1:5
    a = 500;
    b = 1000000;
    x(:,i) = round((b-a).*rand(10,1) + a);
end
x = x';

net = feedforwardnet(100,'trainbr');

net.numLayers = 10;
net.trainParam.epochs = 1000;

net.divideFcn = 'dividetrain';
net = train(net,x,y);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The first two sections are really just there to provide any input (x) and any output (y) to train the network. Could also be simpler, just shouldn't be anything linear. My goal really is to just letting the network "memorize" the input output pairs completely.

Comment: How do you expect the network to learn if you provide just one training sample? Also neural nets try to learn a function corresponding to patterns in the data. If you are providing just random inputs and outputs, what pattern do you expect it to learn? Try some of [these](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples.html) examples first.